# Need very small example of WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am beginner to WPF and MVVM structure. Below is my code for View part and relevent files:

**ListOfVehicle**

```
<Window x:Class="Seris.ListOfVehicle"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            Title="ListOfVehcle" Height="600" Width="700"
            xmlns:cnv="clr-namespace:Seris.Converters">
<Window.Resources>
    <cnv:ID2Name x:Key="converter" />
</Window.Resources>

<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center">

    <Label Content="Manage Vehicle" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="27" Margin="261,8,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="103" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="12"/>
    <Label Content="SERIS CAD" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Margin="53,8,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="84" FontWeight="Bold"/>
    <Menu x:Name="ListOfPersonnnel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="32" Margin="10,35,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="603">
        <MenuItem Header="Manage Vehicle &gt;&gt;" />
    </Menu>

    <Button Name="Add_Button" CommandParameter="add"  Command="{Binding OpenAddWindow_Command}"  Content="Add" Height="28" Width="81" Margin="246,396,315,46"/>
    <Button Name="Replace_Button" CommandParameter="replace" Command="{Binding ReplaceButton_Command}" IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnableReplaceButton, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"  Content="Replace" Height="28" Width="81" Margin="345,396,216,46"/>
    <Button Name="Remove_Button" CommandParameter="remove" Command="{Binding RemoveButton_Command}" IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnableReplaceButton, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"  Content="Remove" Height="28" Width="81" Margin="442,396,119,46"/>


    <ListView Name ="Grid" Margin="104,67,185,226" >
        <DataGrid Name="DG" ItemsSource="{Binding ListItems, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRow, Mode=TwoWay}"  SelectionMode="Single" GridLinesVisibility="None" IsReadOnly="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BorderThickness="0">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Vehicle No" Binding="{Binding VehicleNo}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Model" Binding="{Binding Model}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="ManufacturingDate" Binding="{Binding ManufacturingDate}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="IUNo" Binding="{Binding IUNo}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Personnel" Binding="{Binding PersonnelNameSelected, Converter={StaticResource converter} }" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Unique No" Binding="{Binding UniqueNo}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </ListView>


</Grid>

</Window>
```

After doing these I am stuck at one point.What I need is as below, but not sure how to implement.

Suppose, I put 2 TextBoxes in my View part and one Label. (Consider TextBox1, TextBox2 and Label respectively)

What I need is very small example of WPF C#, such that it when I click on specific TextBox, it gives content as well as name of that Textbox in the Label.

i.e. Name is 'TextBox1', Content is 'How are you?'

Comment: It sounds like you're almost setting us an assignment. Where is your attempt?

Comment: [Kindly put some effort into programming first](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/). If you ask regarding specific problems with **your** code, i am sure people will help gladly...

Comment: Take a look here: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/. I even wrote WPF for you in the [searchbox](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/site/search?query=WPF&f%5B0%5D.Value=WPF&f%5B0%5D.Type=SearchText&ac=4).

Comment: Actually I am doing an application for my learning of WPF, just this functionality is remaining. That's why. If u need, I can put my bunch of files but it would be of no use for you.

Comment: Then don't put that bunch of files that are of no use to us. Just show us the relevant excerpt of the code.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Using Triggers and StringFormat can help you do the trick..

```
<Grid>
    <ContentControl>
        <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Name="myTextBlock"/>
                    <TextBox Name="TextBox1"></TextBox>
                    <TextBox Name="TextBox2"></TextBox>
                </StackPanel>
                <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsKeyboardFocused, ElementName=TextBox1}" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Text" TargetName="myTextBlock">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}Name is '{0}', Content is '{1}'">
                                    <Binding ElementName="TextBox1" Path="Name" />
                                    <Binding ElementName="TextBox1" Path="Text" />
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsKeyboardFocused, ElementName=TextBox2}" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Text" TargetName="myTextBlock">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}Name is '{0}', Content is '{1}'">
                                    <Binding ElementName="TextBox2" Path="Name" />
                                    <Binding ElementName="TextBox2" Path="Text" />
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </DataTemplate.Triggers>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
    </ContentControl>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Please don't encourage or reward questions like this.

Comment: @nit: I really appreciate your efforts. I don't know how to prove these audience. I am already a Software Developer in MNC company but I didn't want to confuse u all bu putting bunch of code. By the way I appreciate your efforts, and currently on weekends, awill be back in working days.